# Is there a way to calculate a string height / weight in android?

Tags: android, string, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I create screen with 3 parts that divided with `weightSum` and with:

```
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".....my choose"
```

Now , I success to change the division dynamically  by change the layout param. My problem is that my first part contain textView that contain string that I don't know the length of him( it's change every time ) . It's could be short or very long , so for normal case everything OK but if the string is really long I want to give to first part more 'weight' from screen and I want it to be in relation to the length of the string..

The question is if I could know somehow the 'height' of a string and from there to calculate how much weight the string need ?then I could change again the division ,  Or maybe there is another alternative to my case?

Thanks all!

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content" only for text case.. hope it works ... if text smaller the weight 1 will works

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Thanks but it's not help because the layout that contains the textView has also android:layout_weight:".." so it's always same size...

Answer (score 0):

Better use algorithm to find the length of string, Once you find the length, then change the text size or weigth programatically .

Comment: I know the length of the string , but the question is exactly to what size to change the weight ? I need some details about this string length (maybe the height or something else...)

Comment: Height and width of the string changes with textsize and fontfamily. So change according to the font family . http://alvinalexander.com/photos/android-roboto-fonts-examples .

Comment: Thanks , I try some different solutions to calculate by font and size  with Paint and Rect objects but what change its just the width always , the heights is always the same in this way..

Answer (score 0):

It's sort of a hack. You can use `getWidth` of `TextView` in which you are setting `String` and the base on that width, assign your `weight`.

For example if your `TextView` is `yourTextView`.

```
yourTextView.setText(yourString);
int width = yourTextView.getWidth;
if(width > THRESHOLD)
    setWeight(YOUR_VALUE)
else setWeight(YOUR_VALUE)
```

**NOTE**

If you are not able to find width immediately, you can use `Handler` as it takes sometime to set text.

```
yourTextView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        width = yourTextView.getWidth();
    }
}, 300);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I test it , try to get width and height of the my TextView. The width is always the same ( it's have a sense because it's not change ) but the issue is with the height - I test on strings with diffrent  lengths: 20,40,80,120,200 characters. In 20 the result was 68 , in 40 the result was 127 and then in 80,120,200 it was the same result-128 .. So maybe it's limited or something but I think what return from getHeight/Width is not relate to the string in the TextView ..